# Use Git rebase to condense old commits

Tags: git

Suppose I had a git history that looks like this:

```
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- 
    \            /
     -----E-----
```

Is there a relatively quick way to condense B and C into a single commit?

I would like my final history to look like:

```
-- A -- BC' -- D' --
    \         /
     ----E----
```

It's easy to condense B and C using vanilla rebasing - it seems to be getting the new Commit replacing B and C to become the ancestor or D that is troublesome.

With a branch pointing to D checked out, and running git rebase -i master (predecessor to A), and electing to squash C, my resulting history looks like:

```
A -- BC' -- E'
 \
  --- E
```

Comment: Is [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits) what you're looking for?

Comment: I will certainly need to use that - but if I use the more general uses cases, I always end up with the new B+C combined commit on the tip of a branch (either the --onto branch) or the default option.  I want to keep them in their place historically

Comment: see [Tim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29202469/2293700). That should get you what you want.

Comment: @nihilon, I'm afraid it doesn't :(

Comment: `git rebase -i A -p` then change `C` from `pick` to `fixup`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that this diagram represents your master branch:

```
master: A <- B <- C <- D (what you have)
master: A <- S <- D      (what you want)
```

You can use `git rebase -i`, which is `rebase` in interactive mode.  You will be given a list of commits as shown here:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i master

pick 0vmw31r comment for commit D
pick dnmwe91 comment for commit C
squash 209vmiq comment for commit B
pick d89gmlk comment for commit A
```

Once you are done, type the following to finish the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

By choosing `squash` for commit B, it will combine commit B into commit C, leaving you with what you want.  Keep in mind that you may have merge conflicts from squashing the `B` and `C` commits.

> It's easy to condense B and C using vanilla rebasing - it seems to be getting the new Commit replacing B and C to become the ancestor or D that is troublesome.

It is not only easy to get the new Commit replacing B and C to become the ancestor of D, it is the default behavior.

Comment: This answer won't work.  Please try out the commands you are suggesting before posting as an answer. `master` is not correct in `git  rebase`, and merge commits (`D`) will not show up in interactive rebase with the options you gave for starters.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't quite get me what I want - the B and C commits will still be in my history since C is the predecessor of D.  Your example simplified this out of the problem, so that the git garbage collector removes the commits that are no longer referenced.

Comment: Please update your question so that it is clear what you want.

Comment: Setting the new combined commit to be the ancestor of D is only the default behavior when D has no other ancestors than the commits being combined.  This does not hold for my example, and I believe that D must also become a new commit (D') to reflect the fact that it's set of ancestors needs go from {C, F} to {BC', F}

Comment: Please try doing a "vanilla" rebase as I have laid out in my answer.  If you don't get the expected result, then update your question with the reason why a normal rebase won't behave the way we expect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is *im*possible using `git rebase` "out of the box" as it were (with `--preserve`), but it's easy<sup>1</sup> to do with `git filter-branch` instead, by filtering such that you drop commit `B` entirely.  The filter sequence will then copy the tree for `C` to `C'` and make `C'`'s parent be `A`, and will copy the tree for `D` to `D'` and make `D'`'s parents (there will still be two) be `E` and `C'` respectively.

Note that while I call the copy `C'` here, it has C's tree, which *does* include whatever was changed in `B` as well.  So you can properly call it `BC'` instead and you get just what you drew.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" = id-of-B ]; then skip_commit "$@";
    else git commit-tree "$@"; fi' branchname
```

(fill in the ID for B here, and an appropriate positive-ref; use branchname~5..branchname or similar to reduce the number of commits iterated-over, choosing your `~` value high enough to make filter-branch see what's needed but low enough not to "copy" commits that won't change after all).

You can also do this with lower level git commands (specifically, two `git commit-tree` commands followed by a forced branch-move).  Given footnote 1 below, this might wind up being easier (depends whether `D` is the tip-most commit of the branch in question, and your comfort level with `filter-branch`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Inasmuch as anything with `git filter-branch` can ever be said to be "easy"... :-)  Even once you understand it thoroughly, there's still the post-filtering clean-up to do as well.